# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined" while using two substrings in two different functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have images which are stored as file paths in a spreadsheet.  The image is extracted via Google Apps Script by creating a substring of their file path name and using it to find the image in a pre specified folder.  I to extract 3 signatures per data set, but I am only able to extract one.

```
function motorElectInstallSignature(row, body){
  var signature = row[22];
  var sign = signature.substring(signature.indexOf("/") + 1);
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16C0DR-R5rJ4f5_2T1f-ZZIxoXQPKvh5C");
  var files = sigFolder.getFilesByName(sign);
  var n = 0;
  var file;
  while(files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    n++;
  } if(n>1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alers('there is more than one file with this name' + sign);
  }
  var sigElectInstaller = "%SIGNELECTINSTALL%";
  var targetRange = body.findText(sigElectInstaller); // Finding the range we need to focus on
  var paragraph = targetRange.getElement().getParent().asParagraph(); // Getting the Paragraph of the target
  paragraph.insertInlineImage(1, file.getBlob());// As there are only one element in this case you want to  insert at index 1 so it will appear after the text // Notice the .getBlob()
  paragraph.replaceText(sigElectInstaller, ""); // Remove the placeholder
}
```

This function works as intended with no errors.
This next function is where the error occurs.

```
function motorCommEngineerSig(row, body){
  var signature1 = row[69];
  var signCommEng = signature1.substring(signature1.indexOf("/") + 1);
  var sigFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16C0DR-R5rJ4f5_2T1f-ZZIxoXQPKvh5C");
  var files = sigFolder.getFilesByName(signCommEng);
  var n = 0;
  var file;
  while(files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    n++;
  } if(n>1){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alers('there is more than one file with this name' + signCommEng);
  }
  var sigCommEng = "%SFCE%";
  var targetRange = body.findText(sigCommEng); // Finding the range we need to focus on
  var paragraph = targetRange.getElement().getParent().asParagraph(); // Getting the Paragraph of the target
  paragraph.insertInlineImage(1, file.getBlob());// As there are only one element in this case you want to  insert at index 1 so it will appear after the text // Notice the .getBlob()
  paragraph.replaceText(sigCommEng, ""); // Remove the placeholder
}
```

The error occurs on this line:`var signCommEng = signature1.substring(signature1.indexOf("/") + 1);`
As you can see, there is no difference between both functions, with the exception of some variable names and a row number.  These functions work as intended multiple times in a script that I have previously written.  These functions serve the same purpose here as they did in my previous script and they are written the exact same way.

The speradsheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nrRMW-XnoqVLOv87Rf0ufPDGQ0iwfFLA5HigeqhkCg/edit?usp=sharing)

The Script can be found [here](https://script.google.com/d/1TnsVCjlNuuqLdZEKiypSBMw-ddLr0aIR42OQs2WV_W8AErg2ipv8BsQO/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the input data. Can you provide some sample data where you encounter the error?

Comment: I have added the spreadsheet where the data is contained.  Thank you for any help you can provide. @AdamStevenson

Comment: Hello Ciaran, could you please describe what is the exact error you are getting?
Furthermore, regarding your input data, could you describe where your file paths are stored? I haven't managed to find them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @carlesgg97 The images are stored in a folder called "Signatures". The data in the spreadsheet related to the images is a file path which points to specific images in the Signatures folder. The error I am getting is on `substring` in `motorCommEngineerSig(row, body) `. I need to make a substring of the file path, starting at the very first character after `/` to get the file name which allows me to find the image and append it to a template.  In the function `motorElectInstallSignature(row, body)` there are no problems. The typeError only persists in `motorCommEngineerSig(row, body) `.

Comment: @CiaranCrowley Hello, were you able to fix your issue with any of below answers? I am having a similar issue and would like to know about your issue's outcome... Thanks!

Comment: @carlesgg97 Hello, yes this problem has now been resolved.  I failed to read the answers properly, and after reading your latest comment, I read through them again more carefully and realised that I was only getting a data within the range of 47 columns, rather than all 73. On line 6 of the script in ```choose_row_method_motors_valves.gs```, ```var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 10, 47) ```.  I changed this to ```var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 10, 73)``` and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is with how you're defining `signature1` in `motorCommEngineerSig()`:

```
var signature1 = row[69];
```

`row[69]` refers to the 70th (0-index) column in your data. However, where you've previously defined `row`, you only provided 47 columns of data:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 10, 47).getValues();
  .
  .
  .
var row = data[rowNumber];
```

In `motorElectInstallSignature()`, you defined the signature in column 22, which is in range of the data and why it worked for that function.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError):

> A TypeError may be thrown when an operand or argument passed to a function is incompatible with the type expected by that operator or function, or when attempting to modify a value that cannot be changed, or when attempting to use a value in an inappropriate way.

That happens essentially because the element you get from row, in your case `row[69]` does not have a `substring` method. That could be because:

1. The element exists in the row, but is not of the `string` type. The element could instead be a Number, Object, etc.
2. The element is not present in the list (the list does not hold that many items). In this case, the `row[69]` expression returns `undefined`, which does not posses that method thus returning an error when invoked.

Based on your particular error message, the second option seems to be the one occurring.

In order to fix your issue I recommend you use the built-in debugging tools such as [`console.log`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#logformatorobject,-values) or [`Logger.log`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(Object)).

Furthermore, I would also recommend you check out the following link: [Apps Script troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting).